# Running Pytest test cases in transaction isolation in a FastAPI setup

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have a FastAPI application, with MySQL and `asyncio`.

I have been trying to integrate some test cases with my application, with the ability to rollback the changes after every test case, so that all test cases can run in isolation.

This is how my controller is set up, with a DB dependency getting injected.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine

async def get_db_connection_dependency():
    engine = create_async_engine("mysql+aiomysql://root:root@mysql8:3306/user_db")
    connection = engine.connect()
    return connection

class UserController:
   async def create_user(
            self,
            request: Request,
            connection: AsyncConnection = Depends(get_db_connection_dependency)

    ) -> JSONResponse:
        
        # START TRANSACTION
        await connection.__aenter__()
        transaction = connection.begin()
        await transaction.__aenter__()

        try:
            do_stuff()
        except:
            await transaction.rollback()
        else:
            await transaction.commit()
        finally:
            await connection.close()
      
        # END TRANSACTION
        
        return JSONResponse(status_code=201)
```

I have a test case written using Pytest like so

```
import pytest

app = FastAPI()

@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    with TestClient(app=app) as c:
        yield c

class TestUserCreation:
    CREATE_USER_URL = "/users/create"
    
    def test_create_user(self, client):
        response = client.post(self.CREATE_USER_URL, json={"name": "John"})
        assert response.status_code == 201
```

This test case works and persists the newly created user in the DB, but like I said earlier, I want to rollback the changes automatically once the test case finishes.

I have checked a few resources online, but none of them were helpful.

1. [This link](https://aalvarez.me/posts/python-transactional-tests-using-sqlalchemy-pytest-and-factory-boy/) talks about using factory objects, but I can't use factory objects here because my controller requires the DB connection as a dependency.
   Plus, the controller itself is updating the DB, and not a "mocked" factory object.
2. I then searched for ways to inject the dependency manually. This was in the hopes that if I can create a connection manually BEFORE calling the API in my test case and inject it as the required dependency, then I can also forcefully rollback the transaction AFTER the API finishes.

   - So, I came across [this](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2894), which talks about a way to get a dependency to use outside of a controller, but not how to inject it into the controller manually.
3. The [official FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-database/) aren't very exhaustive on how to rollback persisted data in a DB-related test case.

The only way I can think of is to not inject the DB connection as a dependency into the controller, but attach it to the Starlette request object in the request middleware. And then in the response middleware, depending on an env var (`test` vs `prod`), I can ALWAYS rollback if the var is `test`.

But this seems over-engineering to me for a very fundamental requirement of a robust testing suite.

Is there any readily-available, built-in way to do this in FastAPI? Or is there any other library or package available that can do it for me?

If Pytest isn't the best suited framework for this, I'm more than happy to change it to something more suitable.

Appreciate any help I can get.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you look at using FastAPIs `app.dependency_overrides` as shown in the link above? That way you can wrap the `get_db` call in your own function that calls the original get_db call, starts the transaction, yields the session, then rolls back the session afterwards. It'll be completely transparent to your application, and you can set up the dependency override inside a pytest fixture, so that you can either initialize it in your test client setup or on a per test setup. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/

Comment: Usually you don't want to handle connections manually either, as they should belong in a connection pool - but that would depend on how you're connecting to SQLAlchemy - that being said, in this case you could have a dependency on a _transaction_ instead of on getting the database connection; it seems like you have a lot of setup (and manually calling dunder methods isn't a good thing - use them in the context they were designed to be used (usually `async with`?))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this.

I moved all transaction and connection handling into the dependency, with the controller doing nothing with the connection object. This meant that my actual API dependency can have the usual `commit` and `rollback` functions called for their appropriate scenarios, and my override dependency in my test case will always call `rollback` no matter what.

My main problem was that I was letting my controller do some of the DB connection stuff which complicated things.